# CentOS6 system-config-packages missing?

Tags: centos, centos6

I've just installed CentOS 6 with gnome but the graphical package manager no longer appears to be there.

I've tried installing both system-config-packages and pirut using Yum but neither finds anything. I've checked the package lists and it doesn't appear to be there.

I looked at [this list](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/3/srodzaj/1/search/system-config-packages) which doesn't imply that there is an RPM at all for CentOS6. The package manager is available during the install, however. I don't recall seeing an option to include it in the installer but that's not to say it isn't there- I just don't fancy re installing the OS just to check if it's there.

Has the package been superseded by another package by a different name, or has it been removed completely? If so, are there any other graphical package managers I can try?

I generally use Yum but as I'm experimenting with CentOS6 at the moment it's just nice to have a quick graphical representation of the packages available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 uses [PackageKit](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-PackageKit.html) as the graphical package manager.

I presume CentOS 6 does the same.

Comment: It uses (or would appear to) PackageKit for it's updates but it isn't the equivalent of system-config-packages as far as I can tell